# Flatten visible layers into a new one in Sketch

Tags: layers, sketch-app, flatten

Is there any way to create a new layer which is an image of the flattened visible layers?

Basicly the equivalent of Photoshop's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut in Sketch.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is! Under the Layer menu is `Flatten Selection to Bitmap`.
I've bound mine to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> via the Keyboard system settings.

[image: Flatten Selection to Bitmap]

Comment: Thank you :) This option however doesn't create a new layer without removing the others as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut way to do this, you could however use the method mentioned above, just make sure you duplicate the layers before you flatten them to bitmap.

2 shortcuts are still better than a whole set of clicks I guess?

Comment: Thanks. Rather than that I guess it would be easier to flatten to Bitmap, copy the resulting bitmap, undo and paste it.

Comment: That's 4 steps instead of 2... Duplicate > Flatten to bitmap = shorter = faster :)